# closed curve integration

Tags: calculus, integration

[image]

I know that there are 3 parts that I have to look at, the parts being from $(4,0)$ to $(0,0)$, $(4,2)$ to $(4,0)$ and from $(0,0)$ to $(4,2)$ following $x=y^2$.
I have changed $F$ to $(2+3x-y^2)dx + (1+x)dy$ and for the first part I mentioned I tried doing the integral from $4$ to $0$ on $(2+3x)$ as $y = 0$ and then $dy = 0$ however im not sure if this would also make $x = 0$ as well due to $x= y^2$ and then I am also stuck on how to deal with the other 2 parts.

https://ibb.co/Bf5bSqz

i chose to put the integral of 0 at the bottom and 2 at the top as it is going from 0 to 2 on the y axis

https://ibb.co/bHncVSD

for part b i chose to put 2 at the bottom and 0 at the top as it is going from 2 in the y axis to 0

for part c i chose to put 4 at the bottom and 0 at the top as it is going from 4 to 0 on the x axis

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you learned about Green's theorem yet?

Comment: i have not yet learnt about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counter-clockwise is the convention, and I find it easier to follow the counter-clockwise paths in the set-up, and flip the signs at the end.

There are two ways you can go by.

1) we have 3 contours.

path 1, $(0,0) \to (4,0)$

$\mathbf{r} = (x,y) = (t,0)\\
d\mathbf{r} = (1,0)\ dt\\
\int_0^4 F\cdot d\mathbf r = \int_0^4 (2 + 3t - 0^2, 1+t)\cdot(1,0) \ dt = \int_0^4 2 + 3t  \ dt $

path 2, $(4,0) \to (4,2)$

$\mathbf{r} = (x,y) = (4,t)\\
d\mathbf{r} = (0,1)\ dt\\
\int_0^2 F\cdot d\mathbf r = \int_0^2 (2+3\cdot 4 - t^2, 1+4)\cdot(0,1) \ dt = \int_0^2 5\ dt$

path 3, $(4,2) \to (0,0)$

$\mathbf{r} = (x,y) = (t^2, t)$  Had you wanted to say $(x,y) = (t,\sqrt t)$ that would ve fine, too.  But, why introduce a radical?  Also note that $t$ will be going from 2 to 0 over this section of the contour.

$d\mathbf{r} = (2t, t)\ dt\\
\int_2^0 F\cdot d\mathbf r = \int_0^2 (2+3t^2 - t^2, 1+t^2)\cdot(2t,1) \ dt = -\int_0^2 4t + 4t^3 + 1 +t^2  dt$

I have flipped the direction and changed the sign in the last line.

Sum the 3 paths.  Or, since we have been asked to go clockwise take the negative of the sums.

Alternatively, you can apply Green's theorem.

Around a closed contour

$F(x,y) = (P(x,y), Q(x,y))$

$\oint P \ dx + Q\ dy = \iint \frac {\partial Q}{\partial x} -  \frac {\partial P}{\partial y} \ dx \ dy$

$\int_0^2 \int_0^{y^2} 1 + 2y\ dx\ dy$

And again since this is clockwise:

$-\int_0^2 \int_0^{y^2} 1 + 2y\ dx\ dy$

If I set these up correctly, you should get the same result either way.

Comment: woudnt it be the other way around with the paths , eg ,(4,2) to (4,0) as it is going clockwise

Comment: Counter-clockwise is conventional, and that is what I have done.  I see that in the description it does say clockwise.  That will flip all of the signs.

Comment: i was able to obtain the integral for paths 1 and 2 you have however from my image i linked above the integral i got for path 3 is different and im not sure why, and also if i left it as clockwise would that affect me in anyway or do i have to make them counter clockwise

Comment: as you have a 8t^3 but i have a 4t^3

Comment: It is $(2+3x - y^2\cdots,$ I had worked it out with $+y^2$ this is why I had $8t^3.$  Corrected now.

Comment: If you go clockwise, at each path you will get the negative from what you would have going counter-clockwise.

Comment: would i be able to leave the answer in a negative format or is that not allowed as from an example  in lectures the answer was left as negative

Comment: Traveling clockwise, I expect it will be a negative.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $x \neq y^2$ on the line between $(4,0)$ and $(0,0)$!

The integration over the vertical line follows a very similar reasoning to the one you already made.

To integrate over the parabolic curve, note that $x = y^2 \rightarrow dx = 2 \cdot y \cdot dy$ and substitute all $x$ and $dx$ by (some function of) $y$ and $dy$. You are left with a single integration variable, $y$. What are the integration boundaries?

Comment: woudnt i be integrating from right to left as its going clockwise , what i mean was that 4 was at the bottom of the integral sign and  0 was at the top

Comment: I wasn't very clear in my wording. Your method is fully correct

Comment: i was wondering if you could check some images to check if i am doing it correctly , i will be able to add them in edit

Comment: i have added the images

Comment: That seems to be the right method :)

Comment: i also integrated the curve with the x variable and got the same answer of 86/3 so i was wondering if its possible to do it that way aswell and would it be ok to keep it as a minus sign

Comment: Yes, you can choose either variable! The minus signs should be the same either way, though